# Change background image based on tags

Tags: php, functions, tags, custom-background

I'm in a great need for little php script help.

My dyslexia makes me dependent on already written scripts and help from others.

I've found a site that has a short script that changes the background based on what tags the post have, but they want $55 bucks for it and I don't have so much money.

So what I'm after is a script to add to the functions.php that if a post has the tag "red 001" it will use the /img/red001.jpg as background, and if a tag in the post is "blue 003” it will use the /img/blue003.jpg as background.

For a normal coder, this would take 5 minutes, but I can't do it by myself, can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually fixed a solution, this solution uses a custom field in the post, and based on that, loads a background to the post.

To get ride of the issue with different formats on the background image, I got help from (don't remember the name) to write a code where it first tries to load background.jpg, and if that fail, it will load background.gif and so on.
So by adding this code to functions.php, will do the trick

```
// set background based on custom field in post
    function rbpet_post_background () {

        if ( empty( $background = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'usp-custom-background_image', true ) ) ) return;
        $base = "https://example.com/img/backgrounds/";
        $extensions = array( ".jpg" , ".gif" , ".mp4" );

        foreach ( $extensions as $ext ) {

            $file = $base . $background . $ext;
            $file_headers = @get_headers( $file );
            if ( $file_headers[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ) {
                $background_url = $file;
                break;
            }

        }

       if ( empty( $background_url ) ) return;
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
                body { background-image: url( "<?php echo ($background_url); ?>")!important; 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    }
            </style>
    <?php
    }

    add_action( "wp_head" , "rbpet_post_background" );
```